# A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo

Tags: java, maven, jar

Trying to compile and this error always appear

I am not suppose to modify the pom file, thats why we have to add it locally, the command line I use is certanly correct because ive used it already for 50 other .jars and none of them gave me an issue and it appears in the .m2 folder

But even though I modify the pom file the error still appears

I've tried:

-changing jdk from 8 to 6, and also maven versions from 3.6.1 to 3.2.5
 (each of them with both jdk versions)

-different .jars (1.0, 1.0.1 and the one currently 1.0.2)

-upgrading project

-deleting .m2 file

-using jars from 2 different websites (mvnrepository and codehaus )local 
 machine (in case it was corrupted)

My mvn install:install line:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=xml-maven-plugin-1.0.2.jar 
-DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DartifactId=xml-maven-plugin 
-Dversion=1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependecy>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependecy>
```

My error message

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maveplugin:1.0.2:
transform (default) on project gevi-ws: Execution default of goal 
org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0.2:transform failed: A required 
class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-
plugin:1.0.2:transform: org/codehaus/plexus/resource/loader
```

/ResourceNotFoundException
...............................................

Comment: You should not use a plugin as dependency. Furthermore I strongly recommend to add the plugin to your pom file and let maven automatically download everything which is needed which is obviously the issue here...

Comment: I've tried like that as well, sorry forgot to add it in my question